# Tried making a button touchable by making a new button class. Is there something wrong with the code for the Button class that I have made?Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the code in XML showing that I tried to make a new button and use it

```
<com.example.tree.buttonmovement.TouchableButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rightarrow"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

This is the Java Button Class that I made

```
Public class TouchableButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton 
{
    public TouchableButton(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // do what you want
        super.performClick();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my code using the TouchableButton in the MainActivity which is supposed to change a number every time the Timer runs through the code and the button is held down

```
TouchableButton button = (TouchableButton) findViewById(R.id.right);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.performClick();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    timerX.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            currentX+=5;
                        }
                    },0,20);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Released
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? There's no question here...

Comment: I have added a question